# WPF Binding between pages / Transfer data between view models

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I need to transfer data between pages and do "binding" on it.
On the first page i have textbox bound to "Username" property.
Every page has its own viewmodel, after clicking a button in the first page i've done something like this

```
SecondPageViewModel.Username = this.Username;
```

In second page i have textblock bound to Username property, but after page changes, the second page show no text.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Username}" />
```

The only way i found and works is to in the second page viewmodel in the constructor make a task which updates the username.

```
Task.Run(async () => 
{
    while(true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(200);
        this.Username = FirstPageViewModel.Username;
    }
});
```

Is there any other way to do that? By making task here, it isn't always working, sometimes if i change page too fast, it won't show username anyway.

Every viewmodel implements INotifyPropertyChanged + FodyWeaver.

Comment: How is SecondPageViewModel.Username declared?

Comment: you must go through Messaging betwwen viewmodel; https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2014/06/25/how-to-send-string-and-content-messages-with-mvvm-light-messenger/

Comment: public static Username { get; set } = ""; in both view models

Comment: I would use events between ViewModels to communicate the changes of `FirstPageViewModel.Username` to the `SecondPageViewModel`. There's no point of changing the `Username` if it didn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following my comment, here's some simple implementations using events.

- A first implementation is `FirstPageViewModel is parent of SecondPageViewModel`. You can see the event subscription in the `SecondPageViewModel` constructor.
- A second implementation is `FirstPageViewModel is on the same level of SecondPageViewModel`. This uses a [Mediator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) between the two ViewModels. It is basically removing the dependency of `FirstPageViewModel` from `SecondPageViewModel`
- A third one would be to create your own delegate on `FirstPageViewModel` for `SecondPageViewModel` to subscribe on. It's basically the same thing as `PropertyChanged`, but you can configure what event arguments you are ready to pass.

Here's a demo:

```
public delegate void UsernameChangedEventHandler(string username);

public class FirstPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // 3) Third implementation
    public event UsernameChangedEventHandler UsernameChanged;

    private string _username;
    public string UserName
    {
        get { return _username; }
        set
        {
            _username = value;

            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("UserName"));

            if (UsernameChanged != null)
                UsernameChanged(this.UserName);
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public class SecondPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string _username;
    public string UserName
    {
        get { return _username; }
        set
        {
            _username = value;

            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("UserName"));
        }
    }

    public SecondPageViewModel()
    {
    }

    public SecondPageViewModel(FirstPageViewModel parent)
    {
        // 1) First implementation
        parent.PropertyChanged += FirstPageViewModel_OnPropertyChanged;

        // 3) Third Implementation
        parent.UsernameChanged += Parent_UsernameChanged;
    }

    private void Parent_UsernameChanged(string username)
    {
        this.UserName = username;
    }

    private void FirstPageViewModel_OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        FirstPageViewModel parent = (FirstPageViewModel) sender;
        if(args.PropertyName.Equals("username", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            this.UserName = parent.UserName;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public class ParentViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private FirstPageViewModel _firstPageViewModel;
    private SecondPageViewModel _secondPageViewModel;

    public ParentViewModel()
    {
        // 2) Second implementation
        _firstPageViewModel = new FirstPageViewModel();
        _secondPageViewModel = new SecondPageViewModel();

        _firstPageViewModel.PropertyChanged += FirstPageViewModel_PropertyChanged;


        // 3) Third Implementation
        _firstPageViewModel.UsernameChanged += FirstPageViewModel_UsernameChanged;
    }

    private void FirstPageViewModel_UsernameChanged(string username)
    {
        _secondPageViewModel.UserName = username;
    }

    private void FirstPageViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        FirstPageViewModel firstPageViewModel = (FirstPageViewModel)sender;
        if (args.PropertyName.Equals("username", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            _secondPageViewModel.UserName = firstPageViewModel.UserName;
        }
    }
}
```